# Pandas: splitting text into two parts with unequal lengths

Tags: python, string, pandas, substring

I am looking for a substring functionality in pandas: Given a series of positions, I want to select the substring `[0:pos_i]` from each row `i`:

```
>>> text = pd.Series(['123456789', '987654321'])
0    123456789
1    987654321
dtype: object

>>> pos = pd.Series([3,6])
0    3
1    6
dtype: int64
```

Output should be:

```
>>> pd.Series(['123', '987654'])
0    123
1    987654
dtype: object
```

Even better would be splitting into two columns in a dataframe:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([['123', '456789'], ['987654', '321']])
        0       1
0     123  456789
1  987654     321
```

Answer (score 1):

For the simple case of splitting into 2 pieces only:

```
tokens = []
for i, row in text.iteritems():
    tokens.append((row[:pos[i]], row[pos[i]:]))

df = pd.DataFrame(tokens)
```

Or written as a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(row[:pos[i]], row[pos[i]:]) for i, row in text.iteritems()])
```

Gives:

```
>>> df
        0       1
0     123  456789
1  987654     321

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```